# Is it possible to use mass assignment in golang?

Tags: go, struct, types, variable-assignment, mass-assignment

I have my struct like this:

```
type User struct {
    Id uint64
    Email string
}
```

And I know, that I can declare it like this:

```
user := User{
    Id: 1,
    Email: "test@example.com",
}
```

And I can update it like this:

```
user.Id = 2
user.Email = "test1@example.com"
```

Is it possible to use similar construction like for creating but for **updating** struct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there really isn't an equivalent multi-property setter.

**EDIT:**

Possibly with reflection you could do something like:

```
updates := user := User{
  Email: "newemail@example.com",
}
//via reflection (pseudo code)
for each field in target object {
  if updates.field is not zero value{
     set target.field = updates.field
  }
}
```

The reflection part could be factored into a function `updateFields(dst, src interface{})`, but I would generally say the complexity is not worth the savings. Just have a few lines of setting fields one by one.

Comment: can it be done with reflection? for example, I have list of fields which should be updated and need to go throw it and do some stuff

Comment: thank you. I know, it's ugly and I really don't like it. It's because of https://github.com/astaxie/beego/issues/2602 and I don't know how to avoid it

Answer (score 1):

It's not the same, but you can use the multivalue return functionality to set them in one line.

https://play.golang.org/p/SGuOhdJieW

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type User struct {
    Id    uint64
    Email string
Name  string
}

func main() {
    user := User{
        Id:    1,
        Email: "test@example.com",
    Name: "Peter",
    }
    fmt.Println(user)

    user.Id, user.Email = 2,  "also-test@example.com"
    fmt.Println(user) // user.Name = "Peter"

}
```

Comment: Thank you! Looks good, but for a lot of properties it will looks ugly

Comment: You could wrap it in a function

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type User struct {
    Id    uint64
    Email string
}

func main() {
    user := User{
        Id:    1,
        Email: "test@example.com",
    }
    fmt.Println(user)

    user = User{
        Id:    2,
        Email: "also-test@example.com",
    }
    fmt.Println(user)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/5-ME3p_JaV

Comment: You can do that if you add `Name: user1.Name` @OleksandrSavchenko?

Comment: It's not the same